# Is there a way to call data from columns specified by a string that differs for different rows of a data frame?

Tags: r

In this example, the variable "colnumber" indicates which column's data I want to extract.

```
col1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
col2 <- c("b", "a", "c")
col3 <- c("c", "b", "a")
colnumber <- c(1, 2, 3) 
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, colnumber)
```

I tried to create a variable a_col and copy the data from the numbered column designated by "number" using paste0 to create the string and then converting it to a symbol:

```
df %%
mutate(a_col = !!sym(paste0("col", colnumber)))
```

What I am expecting is a new variable a_col that has the value "a" for all 3 rows.

Instead I get the following error msg:

Error in local_error_context(dots = dots, .index = i, mask = mask) :
promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dplyr-based solution using a rowwise `mutate()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(a_col = cur_data()[[paste0("col", colnumber)]]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Or a base R solution using `sapply()` to index into each row:

```
df$a_col <- sapply(
  seq(nrow(df)), 
  \(row) df[row, paste0("col", df[row, "colnumber"])]
)

df
```

Result from either approach:

```
  col1 col2 col3 colnumber a_col
1    a    b    c         1     a
2    b    a    b         2     a
3    c    c    a         3     a
```

NB, if `col1`, `col2`, etc., are the 1st, 2nd, etc., columns in your dataset, you can omit the `paste0("col")` and just use the numeric index.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
library(purrr)

df %>% mutate(a_col = map(colnumber, ~df[[paste0("col", .x)]]))
```

Comment: Makes sense to me. But now it generates a different error:

Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `a_col = df[[paste0("col", colnumber)]]`.
Caused by error in `.subset2()`:
! recursive indexing failed at level 2
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Edited my answer, see if that works now. you could try using the `map()` function from the `purrr` package to apply the [[]] operator to each element in the `colnumber` vector.

Comment: This created a variable with a list of three characters from all 3 columns. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
df$a_col <- vapply(
  seq_along(df$colnumber), 
  function(i){
    df[i, df$colnumber[i], drop = TRUE]
  },
  character(1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a vectorized operation with row/column index

```
df$a_col <- df[1:3][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$colnumber)]
```

-output

```
> df
  col1 col2 col3 colnumber a_col
1    a    b    c         1     a
2    b    a    b         2     a
3    c    c    a         3     a
```